# K-means in Spark (Scala) - How to map cluster numbers back to customer ID when model was made from standardized data

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, k-means

The following code was used to get the model. The issue I am facing is in mapping back the cluster numbers to customer IDs. This is because, my model is trained on standardized data but the data with customer ID has data which is not standardized. I am not able to figure out how to map back.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.StandardScaler
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
// importing the data for clustering
val data = sc.textFile("hdfs://path/data_for_clus1") 
val vectors = data.map(s => s.split('\1')).map(s => s.slice(1, s.size)) 
val parsedData =  vectors.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.map(_.toDouble)))    

val dataAsArray = parsedData.map(_.toArray)  
// Using Standardscaler to standardize data
val features = dataAsArray.map(a => Vectors.dense(a))
val scaler = new StandardScaler(withMean = true, withStd = true).fit(features) 
val scaledFeatures = scaler.transform(features) 


val WSSEBuffer = ArrayBuffer[Double](); 
// K-means
val numClusters = 20
val numIterations = 500
val clusters = KMeans.train(scaledFeatures, numClusters, numIterations)
val WSSSE = clusters.computeCost(scaledFeatures)
```

Using the model 'clusters', I want to give cluster numbers to customer ID present in the table 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

parse your data to

```
val newdata = Array[(customerID, featureArray)]
```

then

```
newdata.map(customer => (customer._1, clusters.predict(customer._2)))
```

not sure if this is a efficient way or not